# add new syslog facility

Tags: logs, syslog, rsyslog

I would like to use syslog to log messages coming from my PHP based site.
My question is - can I add custom facility name?
I know there are predefined facilities like:

```
auth, authpriv, cron, dæmon, kern, lpr, mail, mark, news, syslog, user, UUCP and local0 through local7.
```

And as I understand I could use local0 - local6 facilities for this.

But I just feel that if I could add something like this to syslog:

```
mySiteName.* /var/log/mySiteName.log
```

It would be visually easier to understand for others.
Unfortunately above line results in:

```
rsyslogd-3000: unknown facility name "mySiteName"
```

So - is there a way to use custom facility name?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [syslog](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/syslog.html) interface only allows a fixed set of facilities, defined by constants in `/usr/include/sys/syslog.h`. The only provision for custom facilities are `local0` through `local7`.

What you can do to separate the logs of various servers is use filters to match on the origin or text of each log message. Rsyslog has fairly powerful [filters](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html) (read the [properties available for matching](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/property_replacer.html)).

Comment: on ARM platforms the mentioned header is in (eg. RPiOS) `/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/syslog.h`

Answer (score 9):

Not exactly applying to the question but hopefully useful example for daemons not providing their own facility:

```
:programname, isequal, "uptimed" /var/log/uptimed.log
```

Comment: Which syslog implementation are you referring to?  (Or is this standard?)

Comment: Adding this line to /etc/rsyslog.conf worked with rsyslogd 8.4.2