# How to change ssh log location from /var/log/secure to custom location in rhel 6?

Tags: ssh, rsyslog

By default in RHEL 6, SSH server logs are sent to `/var/log/secure`. I want to change this location to a custom one. Is it possible to do that?

I have tried modifying the `rsyslog.conf` file, but it does not work.

Comment: How did you modify the file? And did you restart rsyslogd after making the change?

Answer (score 5):

Choose an unused local facility. For example local3 is not used for any logging in your system. So first edit `/etc/sshd_config` configuration file.

```
 #SyslogFacility AUTH
 SyslogFacility local3
```

Now configure rsyslog to log local3 logs to a file that you need. Add the following to your `/etc/rsyslog.conf` .

```
#Logging sshd to another file. Using local3 facility.
local3.* /SOME/PATH/YOU/WANT/YOUR/SSHD/LOGS/TO-BE.log
```

Where `/SOME/PATH/YOU/WANT/YOUR/SSHD/LOGS/TO-BE.log`  of course  should be replaced by the location of the file where you want to redirect your sshd logs, sensibly I hope that could be `/var/log/sshd.log` .

Then as usual, restart the service:

```
   service rsyslogd restart
```

Comment: Good idea to clarify: [*The only provision for custom facilities are local0 through local7*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21064/163265)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change/add the following line in your `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file:

```
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/custom_secure
```

and restart your `rsyslog` daemon (`service rsyslogd restart`).

Comment: authpriv is not privileged to ssh so this isnt a good solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also specifically isolate sshd log to another file.

Append this line to `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

`:programname, isequal, "sshd" /var/log/sshd.log`

Note that sshd log will be written to both `/var/log/secure` and `/var/log/sshd.log`, but this way we can isolate sshd to another file (no polkitd, no sudo, etc.)